# C : Array of bytes which stores unsigned ints using 3 bytes

Tags: c, arrays, byte

this is my first question so please take me easy, I'm a beginner in C and I'd like to know more about it.
Could someone help me write this function? I can't really picture how the array of bytes should look like:

"An array of bytes stores unsigned ints each using 3 bytes, least significant byte first. Write a function that takes an array and its byte length and prints the numbers in hex."

Comment: What is the picture you have in mind of what an array looks like?

Comment: 3-byte ints? what is this? a cpu for unaligned access?

Comment: I know for example that an array of integers looks sth like this a[40]={1,2,4,5} But what about an array of bytes? Is it like a[40]={10111111,10111110,10111000} ?

Answer (score 1):

[lowbyte-of-value-0, middlebyte-of-value-0, highbyte-of-value-0,lowbyte-of-value-1, middlebyte-of-value-1, highbyte-of-value-1, ... lowbyte-of-value-n, middlebyte-of-value-n, highbyte-of-value-n]

Your task is to walk through that array, pull the bytes one by one or in groups of 3 as you choose, and reassemble them into unsigned integer values.